# siginfo_t has not been declared: caused by inclusion of a thrift header

Tags: c++, include, thrift, c-preprocessor

This is my `main.cpp`.

```
#include <thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h>

#define <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

When I run `g++ main.cpp`, I get:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/wait.h:148:52: error: ‘siginfo_t’ has not been declared
 extern int waitid (idtype_t __idtype, __id_t __id, siginfo_t *__infop,
                                                    ^
```

If I reverse the order of the includes or if I remove either of the includes, compilation succeeds. There is some interaction between these two includes that I don't understand. Compilation only fails when `thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h` is included *before* `sys/wait.h`.

I wanted to see what the preprocessed output looks like, so I run `g++ main.cpp -E -o preprocessed.p; grep -irn -B 10 "siginfo_t" preprocessed.p;`

I get:

```
38168-   } _sigpoll;
38169-
38170-
38171- struct
38172-   {
38173-     void *_call_addr;
38174-     int _syscall;
38175-     unsigned int _arch;
38176-   } _sigsys;
38177-      } _sifields;
38178:  } siginfo_t ;
--
38408-extern int gsignal (int __sig) throw ();
38409-
38410-
38411-
38412-
38413-extern void psignal (int __sig, const char *__s);
38414-
38415-
38416-
38417-
38418:extern void psiginfo (const siginfo_t *__pinfo, const char *__s);
--
38476-# 24 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sigaction.h" 3 4
38477-struct sigaction
38478-  {
38479-
38480-
38481-    union
38482-      {
38483-
38484- __sighandler_t sa_handler;
38485-
38486: void (*sa_sigaction) (int, siginfo_t *, void *);
--
38528-
38529-extern int sigwait (const sigset_t *__restrict __set, int *__restrict __sig)
38530-     __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1, 2)));
38531-
38532-
38533-
38534-
38535-
38536-
38537-extern int sigwaitinfo (const sigset_t *__restrict __set,
38538:   siginfo_t *__restrict __info) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));
38539-
38540-
38541-
38542-
38543-
38544-
38545-extern int sigtimedwait (const sigset_t *__restrict __set,
38546:    siginfo_t *__restrict __info,
--
39462-extern __pid_t wait (void * __stat_loc);
39463-# 125 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/wait.h" 3 4
39464-extern __pid_t waitpid (__pid_t __pid, int *__stat_loc, int __options);
39465-# 135 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/wait.h" 3 4
39466-# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/siginfo.h" 1 3 4
39467-# 24 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/siginfo.h" 3 4
39468-# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
39469-# 25 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/siginfo.h" 2 3 4
39470-# 136 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/wait.h" 2 3 4
39471-# 148 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/wait.h" 3 4
39472:extern int waitid (idtype_t __idtype, __id_t __id, siginfo_t *__infop,
```

It appears to me that siginfo_t *is* declared/defined at line 38171-38178. Why is this not sufficient for its use at line 39472?

Info:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Thrift 0.9.1, configured with `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --with-c_glib=no --enable-tests=no --with-python=no`

Comment: One possibility is that your gtest/gtest.h or its dependencies is including an implementation header it's not supposed to include. (stuff in /usr/include/linux as one example). Another possibility is that thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h or its dependencies defines macros that causes posix extension to be unavailable

Comment: @nos How would I check for the latter? Also, can you say more about how that would explain my preprocessed output - it seems to clearly show that siginfo_t *is* defined.

Comment: Either manual inspection, or possible run g++ -E on a file containing only `#include <thrift/protocol/TProtocol.h>`and `#include <signal.h>` and see if siginfo_t gets defined.

Comment: Would you consider that a bug in the library?

Comment: Another thing to check is that you're not including system headers inside a `namespace {` somewhere.

Comment: @nos Thank you. I've further isolated the problem to TProtocol.h. Gtest is not required to reproduce this issue. I'll update the question momentarily.

Comment: @nos Looks like the `siginfo_t` definition is *inside* the namespace `apache::thrift::protocol`... thanks for the guidance. I'll write up an answer and a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that has now been fixed:

https://github.com/apache/thrift/commit/f4e6e62ea091b94322ecc99756269dbee1c06380

A system header (`sys/param.h`) was included *inside* the `apache::thrift::protocol` namespace.